# How to make a query with or condition in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I make a query with or condition in Mongoid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for "**OR**" query in mongoid.

if you want query like below

`select * from user where id = 10 or name = 'hitesh';`

in rails with mongoid then you have to write query like this

`User.any_of({id: 10},{name: 'hitesh'}).first`

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

`User.or({id: 10},{name: 'hitesh'})`

Answer (score 0):

@Simone Carletti is right but you also can use "mongo-style" notation:

```
# Ruby 1.9+
Person.where(last_name: {"$in" => ["Penn", "Teller"]})
#Ruby 1.9-
Person.where(:las_name => {"$in" => ["Penn", "Teller"]})
```

or simply

```
Person.where(:last_name.in => ["Penn", "Teller"])
```

**upd**

Conditions for two fields?

```
Person.where(:last_name.in => ["Penn", "Teller"], :first_name.in => ["Pedro", "Julio"])
```

Comment: I need the or condition for two fields, lets say first name and last name

Comment: @fl00r do you know how to make this query belong an `OR` instead of an `AND` I mean, `last_name.in ... OR first_name.in: ...`? At the moment it does an `AND`. See this question for what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981407/how-do-i-find-an-object-whose-properties-foo-or-bar-equal-a-query-value