# How do I find an object whose properties foo or bar equal a query value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, querying

I searched google and looked at the docs, but I found no example of this.

I have this object with embedded children:

```
{
  teacher: "Balthazar",
  students: [
    { name: 'Wilfred', sibling: 'Cordelia' },
    { name: 'Mortimer', sibling: 'Arthur' },
    { name: 'Cordelia', sibling: 'Wilfred' },
    { name: 'Arthur' sibling: 'Mortimer' },
  ]
}
```

I want to find `Balthazar`'s students whose `name` or `sibling` is in `['Wilfred', 'Cordelia', 'foo']`. I got it to work this way:

```
criteria_a = balthazar.students.in(name: ['Wilfred', 'Cordelia'])
criteria_b = balthazar.students.in(sibling: ['Wilfred', 'Cordelia'])
criteria_a << criteria_b
```

But is there a cleaner way to chain criteria? I tried chaining, but it doesn't work. It produces an `AND` intersection, not an `OR`.

```
balthazar.students.
  .in(name: ['Wilfred', 'Corderial'])
  .in(sibling: ['Wilfred', 'Corderial'])
```

So, in plain speak, this query is `name is in array **AND** sibling is in array`. But I want `name is in array __OR__ sibling is in array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any_of`

```
balthazar.students.any_of({name: ['Wilfred', 'Cordelia']}, {sibling: ['Wilfred', 'Cordelia']})
```